# Ebay API: Error creating an offer in a marketplace different than the US one

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to create some offers in the Polish marketplaces.

After creating the inventory items I try to call create offer with the same sku but I receive the following message:

```
<400> - {"errors":[{"errorId":25751,"domain":"API_INVENTORY","subdomain":"Selling","category":"REQUEST","message":"POA6765452 could not be found or is not available in the system for the marketplace EBAY_PL.","parameters":[{"name":"text1","value":"POA6765452"},{"name":"text2","value":"EBAY_PL"}]}]}
```

I'm sure that the inventory item exists as I'm able to retrieve it with `GetInventoryItems()`.

I guess the issue is that it doesn't see it in the polish marketplace but when I created the inventory item there isn't any field to specify the markeplace, is there?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I've also tried including the

`("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY-PL")` to my header requests but with no luck..

Comment: I have the same error. For me, I arrived to create an inventory_item and create/publish an offer on french marketplace but when I try to create an offer for the same inventory_item on the deutsche marketplace, i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct Content-Language header while creating inventory item and also the value of marketplaceId when creating an offer.
For example in my case Content-Language header of create inventory is en_AU and marketplaceId when creating an offer is EBAY_AU, so both are Australian values.